# Camera - Auto Night Vision "Mode" (ON only when dark)?

Tags: filter, infrared, camera, diy

I am wondering how night vision "mode" could be automatically switch on & off in commercial CCTV?

Something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ilaXGtsx-DU

(video demonstrate CCTV product with night vision mode)

From what I knew so far, the idea of doing "night vision camera" is by removing "IR Filter" out of the camera, put some IR LED, and there you go - I've succesfully made this fun project too with my OV2640 camera module, and my hacked web cam.

However, by doing this "IR Filter" removal, it won't normally stream correct color when lights are back on (night vision are OFF)

How, then, commercial CCTV could achieve this? They seem using just 1 camera too.. or is there any way to remove "IR Filter" without the need to be physically remove it?

Haven't found any clues (or DIY tutorial) anywhere too. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've correctly identified the problem.

The filter is moved mechanically into and out of the camera. You can hear it click when changing from day to night modes.

Comment: Exactly my point. How those commercial CCTV could do it automatically then?

Comment: EDIT: Re-read your comment again and it seems i miss the whole point. Make sense now - do you have any reference how to do it? Considering "IR Filter" is thin fragile optic piece, placed under very tight space behind the lens @tomnexus

Comment: I don't know exactly how it's done, but there's no reason it has to be so thin, it's just done that way to make the camera smaller. On my baby monitor style camera it is visible in front of the lens.

Comment: A rotating disc with two holes, one with the filter and one without.